# Can I yield or map one element into many in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
val inArray = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
// ...
val outArray = Array("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3", "d1", "d2", "d3")
```

How to map `inArray` to `outArray`?

The idea is to iterate through `inArray` yielding 3 elements (by concatenating an index in this example) from each of its elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that with `flatMap`.

```
inArray.flatMap(c => (1 to 3).map(c+))
```

Comment: Well, what if the suffix is not a numeric index? I actually want to use a custom function of an input element to produce 3 output elements.

Comment: assuming your custom function returns a collection: `inArray.flatMap(customFunction)`

Comment: Thanks. That's it. All the anwers work and get upvotes but you were the first :-)

Answer (score 7):

This can look better using a for-comprehension

```
for {
  s <- inArray
  i <- Array(1, 2, 3) //or other traversable
} 
yield s + i
```

This uses a combination of map and flatMap under the covers as described in detail in the SLS

Answer (score 5):

Using `for`-comprehension.

```
scala> for {
     |   x <- Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
     |   n <- 1 to 3
     | } yield x + n
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3)
```