# Scala: transform a collection, yielding 0..many elements on each iteration

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

Given a collection in Scala, I'd like to traverse this collection and for each object I'd like to emit (yield) from 0 to multiple elements that should be joined together into a new collection.

For example, I expect something like this:

```
val input = Range(0, 15)
val output = input.somefancymapfunction((x) => {
  if (x % 3 == 0)
    yield(s"${x}/3")
  if (x % 5 == 0)
    yield(s"${x}/5")
})
```

to build an `output` collection that will contain

```
(0/3, 0/5, 3/3, 5/5, 6/3, 9/3, 10/5, 12/3)
```

Basically, I want a superset of what `filter` (1 → 0..1) and `map` (1 → 1) allows to do: mapping (1 → 0..n).

## Solutions I've tried

### Imperative solutions

Obviously, it's possible to do so in non-functional maneer, like:

```
var output = mutable.ListBuffer()
input.foreach((x) => {
  if (x % 3 == 0)
    output += s"${x}/3"
  if (x % 5 == 0)
    output += s"${x}/5"
})
```

### Flatmap solutions

I know of `flatMap`, but it again, either:

1) becomes really ugly if we're talking about arbitrary number of output elements:

```
val output = input.flatMap((x) => {
  val v1 = if (x % 3 == 0) {
    Some(s"${x}/3")
  } else {
    None
  }
  val v2 = if (x % 5 == 0) {
    Some(s"${x}/5")
  } else {
    None
  }
  List(v1, v2).flatten
})
```

2) requires usage of mutable collections inside it:

```
val output = input.flatMap((x) => {
  val r = ListBuffer[String]()
  if (x % 3 == 0)
    r += s"${x}/3"
  if (x % 5 == 0)
    r += s"${x}/5"
  r
})
```

which is actually even worse that using mutable collection from the very beginning, or

3) requires major logic overhaul:

```
val output = input.flatMap((x) => {
  if (x % 3 == 0) {
    if (x % 5 == 0) {
      List(s"${x}/3", s"${x}/5")
    } else {
      List(s"${x}/3")
    }
  } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
    List(s"${x}/5")
  } else {
    List()
  }
})
```

which is, IMHO, also looks ugly and requires duplicating the generating code.

### Roll-your-own-map-function

Last, but not least, I can roll my own function of that kind:

```
def myMultiOutputMap[T, R](coll: TraversableOnce[T], func: (T, ListBuffer[R]) => Unit): List[R] = {
  val out = ListBuffer[R]()
  coll.foreach((x) => func.apply(x, out))
  out.toList
}
```

which can be used almost like I want:

```
val output = myMultiOutputMap[Int, String](input, (x, out) => {
  if (x % 3 == 0)
    out += s"${x}/3"
  if (x % 5 == 0)
    out += s"${x}/5"
})
```

Am I really overlooking something and there's no such functionality in standard Scala collection libraries?

## Similar questions

This question bears some similarity to [Can I yield or map one element into many in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110285/can-i-yield-or-map-one-element-into-many-in-scala) — but that question discusses 1 element → 3 elements mapping, and I want 1 element → arbitrary number of elements mapping.

## Final note

Please note that this is *not* the question about division / divisors, such conditions are included purely for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Just to be clear - if the input collection contains 15, should the output collection contain both 15/3 and 15/5?

Comment: @Ben Yes, exactly, 1 element (15) should map into 2 ("15/3", "15/3).

Answer (score 7):

Rather than having a separate case for each divisor, put them in a container and iterate over them in a for comprehension:

```
val output = for {
  n <- input
  d <- Seq(3, 5)
  if n % d == 0
} yield s"$n/$d"
```

Or equivalently in a `collect` nested in a `flatMap`:

```
val output = input.flatMap { n =>
  Seq(3, 5).collect {
    case d if n % d == 0 => s"$n/$d"
  }
}
```

In the more general case where the different cases may have different logic, you can put each case in a separate partial function and iterate over the partial functions:

```
val output = for {
  n <- input
  f <- Seq[PartialFunction[Int, String]](
    {case x if x % 3 == 0 => s"$x/3"},
    {case x if x % 5 == 0 => s"$x/5"})
  if f.isDefinedAt(n)
} yield f(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use some functional library (e.g. scalaz) to express this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def divisibleBy(byWhat: Int)(what: Int): List[String] = 
  (what % byWhat == 0).option(s"$what/$byWhat").toList

(0 to 15) flatMap (divisibleBy(3) _ |+| divisibleBy(5))
```

This uses the [semigroup](https://inoio.de/blog/2014/07/19/type-class-101-semigroup/) append operation `|+|`. For `List`s this operation means a simple list concatenation. So for functions `Int => List[String]`, this append operation will produce a function that runs both functions and appends their results.

Answer (score 1):

If you have complex computation, during which you should sometimes add some elements to *operation global* accumulator, you can use popular approach named [Writer Monad](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Writer.html)

Preparation in scala is somewhat bulky but results are extremely composable thanks to [Monad interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))

```
import scalaz.Writer
import scalaz.syntax.writer._
import scalaz.syntax.monad._
import scalaz.std.vector._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

type Messages[T] = Writer[Vector[String], T]

def yieldW(a: String): Messages[Unit] = Vector(a).tell

val output = Vector.range(0, 15).traverse { n =>
  yieldW(s"$n / 3").whenM(n % 3 == 0) >>
  yieldW(s"$n / 5").whenM(n % 5 == 0)
}.run._1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try collect:

```
val input = Range(0,15)
val output = input.flatMap { x =>
     List(3,5) collect { case n if (x%n == 0) => s"${x}/${n}" }
}
System.out.println(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition for a custom function, might be better with pimp my library pattern

```
def fancyMap[A, B](list: TraversableOnce[A])(fs: (A => Boolean, A => B)*) = {
  def valuesForElement(elem: A) = fs collect { case (predicate, mapper) if predicate(elem) => mapper(elem) }
  list flatMap valuesForElement
}

fancyMap[Int, String](0 to 15)((_ % 3 == 0, _ + "/3"), (_ % 5 == 0, _ + "/5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would us a `fold`:

```
val input = Range(0, 15)
val output = input.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
    case (acc, value) =>
        val acc1 = if (value % 3 == 0) s"$value/3" :: acc else acc
        val acc2 = if (value % 5 == 0) s"$value/5" :: acc1 else acc1
        acc2
}.reverse
```

`output` contains

```
List(0/3, 0/5, 3/3, 5/5, 6/3, 9/3, 10/5, 12/3)
```

A `fold` takes an accumumlator (`acc`), a collection, and a function. The function is called with the initial value of the accumumator, in this case an empty `List[String]`, and each value of the collection. The function should return an updated collection.

On each iteration, we take the growing accumulator and, if the inside `if` statements are `true`, prepend the calculation to the new accumulator. The function finally returns the updated accumulator.

When the `fold` is done, it returns the final accumulator, but unfortunately, it is in reverse order. We simply reverse the accumulator with `.reverse`.

There is a nice paper on folds: [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf), by Graham Hutton.